# J2SSH supported ciphers/Macs

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, j2ssh

I am running a java application which uses J2ssh library to establish the connection to the server.
Last week we migrated to a new IBM server

Here the problem is we are unable to establish FTP/SFTP connection to the new server from my java application. But the connectivity is working fine from other tools.

My doubt is whether the J2SSH library  will support the below ciphers/macs ? because these are the ciphers configured in the new IBM server.

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
MACs hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

Comment: what are the ciphers/macs/keyexchange methods supported by your library? Do you use recent version of J2ssh?

Comment: Hi Jakuje, Currently i am using j2ssh-core-0.2.9.jar library in my application. Just want to know whether this version of jar will support the above mentioned ciphers/macs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your using a very outdated version of J2SSH.

You should upgrade to the more recent open source version [J2SSH Maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick) that supports counter mode ciphers.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I am using j2ssh-core-0.2.9.jar file in my application. Let me check with J2SSH Maverick. Thanks for your advise

Comment: Hi Lee, i currently run into the same issue and tried to extend j2ssh-0.2.9 by aes256-ctr. I implemented the SshCipher abstract class by connecting it to the JCE implementation. To be honest i had a look at your j2ssh-maverick code. The code doesn't crash, but the client waits forever for something. Does the 0.2.9 code base only support cbc algorithms?

Comment: I don't think porting the CTR cipher back to the old version is wise. That API has not been maintained for several years. I'd suggest raising an issue in the J2SSH Maverick Github project to see why your not able to use that, I'm sure it will be something simple thats been overlooked in your code since whilst the API interfaces are very similar there are some differences in how it should be implemented. Especially when coming from J2SSH to the newer API.

Comment: @Lee, I tried to setup the above mentioned ciphers in my test area and tested the connectivity from my application. But i got the error in Transport layer.. java.io.IOException: The socket is EOF... Any idea on the error?.

Comment: This is the old api, I don't support this and it shouldn't be used. A new version is available that is up-to-date and for which updates will be made available if problems are found.

Comment: @Lee, Many thanks for the information.. We have tested J2SSH with CTR ciphers in our test area and the connection is failing for each time. So we planned to migrate our application from J2SSH to JSCH.